# jQuery.post() has a side-effect of changing my URL parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

I have a page with multiple forms. When the users fill in one of the forms, I want to send it to a server. However, I need the browser to keep displaying the original page, so that the users can submit other forms, if they wish to. Hence I cannot use the "action" attribute in the form and a "submit" type of button.

After consulting [the jQuery.post docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), I arrived to the following solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="jsFiles/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form">
            Name:<br> <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
            Email:<br> <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
            <button id="button" onclick="submitForm();"> Submit </button>
        </form>

        <script>
        function submitForm() {
            var postData = $('#form').serialize();
            var jqxhr = $.post("SaveForm.jsp", postData ,function() {
            })
              .done(function() {
                alert("The form was submitted successfully");
              })
              .fail(function() {
                alert("Error submitting the form.");
              })
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code does what I want it to do, but it has a very peculiar and disruptive side-effect of modifying my URL to include the parameters I'm posting.

So when I fill in my name and email, I'm "redirected" to myself, but with the name and email parameters appearing in the URL:

http://localhost:8080/Prototype/TestPost.html?name=Lev&email=Storytime%40gmail.com

Now, I definitely do not want "name=Lev&email=Storytime%40gmail.com" to be a part of my URL. These parameters are also not intended for TestPost.html but rather to SaveForm.jsp, so it's all very wrong.

I also want to mention that SaveForm.jsp works as expected. It receives the parameters, saves them to the database and returns a success response.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

---

### EDIT

Thanks, everybody. I could not avoid the refresh using the "return false" statement, so I had to use jQuery's "on click" option. I also don't understand how using ajax explicitly would make any difference, since jQuery's documentation seems to say that the post is just a syntactic sugar for Ajax.

The complete code which worked for me was:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="jsFiles/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form" method="post">
            Name:<br> <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
            Email:<br> <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
            <button id="button"> Submit </button>
        </form>

    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#button").click(function( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var postData = $('#form').serialize();
                var jqxhr = $.post("SaveForm.jsp", postData ,function() {
                }).done(function() {
                    alert("The form was submitted successfully");
                }).fail(function() {
                    alert("Error submitting the form.");
                })
            });
        });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't especify the `method` attribute on the form it will be `GET` by default, that's why you get the URL params. Also, because you aren't not stopping the default action, your form is being submitted (the reloading effect), so I recommend you the following code to help you:

```
<script> 
 $(function() { //executes js code after html has been loaded
    $("#button").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //avoids to reload the page
      var postData = $('#form').serialize();
      var jqxhr = $.post("SaveForm.jsp", postData ,function() {
      }).done(function() {
          alert("The form was submitted successfully");
       })
       .fail(function() {
           alert("Error submitting the form.");
         })
     }
  });
</script>
```

And remove the onclick at the button to have a cleaner HTML:

```
<button id="button"> Submit </button>
```

Comment: I couldn't have found a better answer! TY

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use jQuery's `on click` and still stick to the `submit` function you can just add `return false;` in the end to prevent the form from submitting.

Like below

```
function submitForm() {
  var postData = $('#form').serialize();
  var jqxhr = $.post("SaveForm.jsp", postData ,function() {
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert("The form was submitted successfully");
  });
  .fail(function() {
    alert("Error submitting the form.");
  })
  return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are not submitting the form by ajax.

Add `return false;`, to that it does not redirect and submit via ajax.

```
  function submitForm() {
      var postData = $('#form').serialize();
      var jqxhr = $.post("SaveForm.jsp", postData, function() {})
        .done(function() {
          alert("The form was submitted successfully");
        })
        .fail(function() {
          alert("Error submitting the form.");
        })

      return false;
    }
```